# ASP.NET Core 3.1 Hot Reload Slow

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a `ASP.NET Core 3.1` project which takes approximately `25 seconds` to build.
While this is not excessive, it's a slow development process, when making several small changes per day.

```
dotnet build
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.7.2+b60ddb6f4 for .NET
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:25.16

The project outputs two dll's, project.dll and project.Views.dll
```

Should hot reloads improve this?

I used the command `dotnet watch run`, and for my project I am not seeing significant improvements. It takes as long as to build the entire project.

I measured the times with hot reload enabled, and it took `38 seconds`.

> I added the `<div>{@DateTime.Now}</div>` to a View, then I made a change in a controller, by changing a single character. My before and after times I measured:
> 21:04 to 21:42 = **38 seconds**

Can this be a problem with how the project is structured? How should I structure my application for optimal compile time, such that the re-build's / hot reload is faster. (not clean builds)

Also should I be seeing similar hot reload times to that of `Java` `spring-boot-devtools`? (a few seconds)

Comment: Probably only .NET 6 (Preview 7 currently) can give you a reasonably fast response time, as it was only recently that Microsoft spent enough time on improving hot reload performance, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-hot-reload/

Comment: If you're on windows check to see if your antivirus has an exclusion for your development folder.
Alternatively, you could build in WSL2 which is more likely to be excluded from scanning.

Comment: Using ASP.NET 3.1 the LTE version. Can someone perhaps perhaps post their hot reload times. It could be my machine/project? I am on MacOS.

Answer (score 1):

Copied from GitHub:

[for 3.1 apps, all dotnet-watch does is re-build the app on file changes.](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36376#issuecomment-917296055)